# Does any Java compiler or JVM ignore a statement for optimization?

Tags: java, optimization

Suppose we have the following statement

```
arrayList.size();
```

This statement in itself does nothing. Will any Java compiler or JVM ignore this statement for optimization purposes?

In effect, the compiler or JVM assumes there are no side effects of the statement and therefore removes it for optimization.

Comment: Possibly. Why don't you test it and look at the bytecode of your class?

Comment: The Java compiler probably can't; what if `arrayList` was some subclass whose `size` method has a side effect? Silly, yes, but still plausible. Some JIT compilers may eliminate it though.

Comment: Does it really do nothing? There could be side-effects in the function call.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure that's exactly what I want to know. Does any compiler make such decisions by assuming there are no side effects.

Comment: Depending on the context of the code it can be *impossible* to prove the call is side effect free. The compiler can not just *assume*, it has to *prove* it has no side effect. One side effect (while often overlooked) is that this *at least* performs a NULL-check.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, it's not exactly a no-op: At the very least, it must perform a null check. Moreover, there may be subclasses of `ArrayList` working differently. In theory, they could even fetch the data from a database or alike. Normally, nobody would subclass an `ArrayList` for doing this, but such a `List` implementation makes some sense.

The compiler (JIT, not javac) must be able to *prove* that it's really a side-effect free. Usually, it's quite simple as

- it knows, if there are any overriden implementation of `ArrayList.size()`.<sup>1</sup>
- If there are none, then it sees that it's a simple getter and inlines it.<sup>2</sup><sup>3</sup>
- This reduces to problem to a useless field load, which gets reduces to the null check.
- The null check can get eliminated too, if it was performed earlier (e.g., due to a previous useless statement :D).
- Otherwise, it can get moved out of the loop, if `arrayList` is a loop invariant.

> Will any Java compiler or JVM ignore this statement for optimization purposes?

So I'd conclude that it's quite probable to happen.

---

<sup>1</sup> This may change later as such a class gets loaded and then a *deoptimization* will take place.
<sup>2</sup> Assuming it decides it's worth optimizing.
<sup>3</sup> This may fail, if the method is already over inlining limit, e.g., due to bad coding style or because of other inlining.